# Pandas: how to explode list of list in a column and use start_number and end_number to give the label from the list exploded?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame df looking like this:

```
    id  data            label
  0 990 'sentence_1'    [[506, 799, label_1]]
  1 991 'sentence_2'    [[413, 709, label_2]]
  2 992 'sentence_3     []
```

I tried this:

```
df["data"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: x["data"][x["label"][0] : x["label"][1] + 1], axis=1
)
df["label"] = df["label"].str[-1]
```

But I have the error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

My sentences look to have the good length.

And sometimes this:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

I don't understand where it comes from

Expected output:

```
    id  data                                     label
 0  990 part_of_sentence_1 from char 506 to 799  label_1
 1  991 part_of_sentence_2 from char 413 to 709  label_2
```

Comment: What do you expect as outcome? Can you update your post, please?

Comment: Thanks I'm doing it. It's updated

Comment: label is a list of list, that's right or a str?

Comment: label is for example : 'country', it is just a string

Comment: I mean `[[506, 799, label_1]]` is a real list of list?

Comment: Yes it is a list of list, first number is first character where to keep and second number is last character to keep on the correspondant row data, and label_1 is the string to assign the split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list of list so you can use `x["label"][1]` because it does not exist (out of range). It should be `x["label"][0][1]`.

Another alternative:

```
# remove not valid lines and remove the outer list
out = df[df['label'].apply(len).astype(bool)].explode('label')

# explode the list of 3 elements into 3 columns
out = out.join(out['label'].apply(pd.Series)) \
         .drop(columns='label') \
         .rename(columns={0: 'start', 1: 'end', 2: 'label'})
```

At this point, output looks like:

```
>>> out
    id        data  start  end    label
0  990  sentence_1      1    3  label_1
1  991  sentence_2      5    8  label_2
```

Now you can do:

```
out['data'] = out.apply(lambda x: x['data'][x['start']:x['end']+1], axis=1)
```

Final output:

```
>>> out[df.columns]
    id  data    label
0  990   ent  label_1
1  991  nce_  label_2
```

Comment: Thank you, this step out['data'] = out.apply(lambda x: x['data'][x['start']:x['end']+1], axis=1) doesn't work. To keep sentence from start to end

Comment: What's wrong with this step? It raises an exception?

Comment: Thanks now it works, maybe I made a typo mistake. When I have [[506, 799, label_1], [102, 123, label_3]] it is duplicated when I display out df at the end. I do drop duplicates, but doesn't understand why I have duplicated rows at the end

Comment: What is duplicated? The columns `data`?

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if it meets your need :)